# Creating a dynamic image in a page through form submission from the previous page - Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a form with a textarea and a submit button in one page
which asks the user to input/paste the url of any image in the textarea

Form link:
https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/sphotos-d.ak/hphotos-ak-frc1/t1.0-9/1538781_610742105669484_767973390_n.jpg

and after the user hits submit

it should redirect it to the next page and create a dynamic image preview in the next page with the entered url in the submitted form from the previous page

Image Page:
https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/sphotos-b.ak/hphotos-ak-prn2/t1.0-9/10157400_610742102336151_950503816_n.jpg

I can't figure out how to catch the image url in the next page and create a preview. Kindly help. Please accept my gratitude in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Useing Javascript you can show image preview on same page.
TO show preview after form submit try to access '$form_state' or override node.tpl.php for particular content type and get text area value using `node_load`  function and add it to `IMG` tag.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

Once submited, you should be able to get the submited image from the "$form_state" array. You then put it in the "src" attribute of a html image tag.

Comment: Hey kind person, thank you. This is what I was looking for. So, should the src look like.
<img src="$form_state">
or do I have to mention any index like $form_state[1]?
Finally, I'm doing this in drupal. So I can't figure out where to insert the code. If I write it in body it won't use the value of $form_state rather it will take it as it is letter by letter which is '$form_state'.

Comment: No, you can't use "$form_state" as this. I think you should learn more about Drupal form api. Check this link: https://drupal.org/node/262422